# UIKit slider always starts at 0

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, storyboard

Here is my slider configuration, see that the minimum value is 1, and the preview in xCode show the slider in the right position.

[image: Config]
[image]

And this is all my code:

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var currentValue: Int = 50

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func showAlert() {
        let message = "The value of the slider is: \(currentValue)"
        let alert = UIAlertController(
            title: "Hello World!",
            message: message,
            preferredStyle: .alert)

        let action = UIAlertAction(
            title: "OK",
            style: .default,
            handler: nil)

        alert.addAction(action)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func sliderMoved(_ slider: UISlider) {
        currentValue = lroundf(slider.value)
    }
}
```

I am not changing the value of the slider anywere, I tried to only have a view with an slider and the generated code of the view controller, and it did not work, the slider always starts its position at 0.

Comment: xCode version = 12.5.1
iOS UIKit generated application

Comment: This could be the fact be a "side effect" in the way that components are loaded and initialise from the storyboard, but I did a test where the min was 0.1, max was 1.0 and the value was 0.5 and that worked just fine.  I would recommend setting the value of the slider to your desired value in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Yep, I did that, I think it is a bug with the M1 version of xCode. ty